# Intercept download and change file name

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I maintain a Google Chrome extension that fixes multiple annoyances with a specific web-based product. One such annoyance is that downloaded files' names are useless so I want to be able to intercept the download and change the file name to a useful one.

As per https://julienharbulot.com/chrome-extension-gutenberg.html and multiple StackOverflow posts, I have:

1. Updated `manifest.json` to include `"permissions": [ "<URL>", "downloads"]` and `"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": false  }`
2. Created `background.js` with the following content just as a proof of concept but nothing gets logged to the console so I can only assume that the product doesn't use `chrome.downloads` or something:

   ```
   chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
       console.log(item.referrer);
       console.log(item.filename);
   });
   ```
3. Updated the content script to include the following but nothing relevant seems to get logged to the console when I trigger a download:

   ```
   MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

   var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
       mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
           if (!mutation.addedNodes) return

           for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
               var node = mutation.addedNodes[i];

               console.log(node);          
           }
       })
   });

   observer.observe(document, {
       subtree: true,
       attributes: true,
       childList: true
   });
   ```

Is there another way that I can detect how the product is invoking downloads and override it?